# recursive function for handling Data.Text replace outputs a way longer text than expected

Tags: haskell

I have a `handleReplace` function in Haskell, which is of type

```
handleReplace :: Character -> T.Text -> T.Text
```

T is just the Data.Text module as a qualified import
So this function takes a Character type, which is defined like this:

```
data Character  = Character (String, String, String, String) [(String,String)] Case String Stringderiving (Read, Show)
```

and a Text value.
It will only care about the list of String tuples, and try to replace every occurrence of the first item in the tuple with the second item in the tuple in the Data.Text string, and that for every element in that list of tuples. One exception is if the occurrence that is being replaced is inside a word that starts with `/`. I defined the function like this:

```
handleReplace :: Character -> T.Text -> T.Text
handleReplace (Character _ []   _ _ _)        s = s
handleReplace (Character _ ((a, b):xs) _ _ _) s = handleReplace emptyCharacter string
                                                where emptyCharacter = Character ([], [], [], []) xs Normal [] []
                                                      string         = T.unwords $ map (\ x 
                                                                                         -> if (T.head x) == '/'
                                                                                                then x
                                                                                                else T.replace (T.pack a) (T.pack b) s
                                                                                      ) $ T.words s
```

Unfortunately though, it does not work. It does not throw any errors, but I am not getting the expected output.
When running

```
handleReplace (Character ([],[],[],[]) [("u","U"),("v","wv")] Normal [] []) $ T.pack "/uu v uu vvuu"
```

I would expect it to return `"/uu wv UU wvwvUU"` (as a Text type obviously) but when I try that in ghci, I get:

```
"/uu /UU /uu /UU wv UU wvwvUU /UU wv UU wvwvUU /UU wv UU wvwvUU ...
```

etc.
Why?

Answer (score 3):

Having a lot of one letter variables at different scopes makes it easy to make
this kind of mistake. I suspect what you wanted to have is

```
else T.replace (T.pack a) (T.pack b) x
```

rather than

```
else T.replace (T.pack a) (T.pack b) s
```

Otherwise, you are performing the replacement on the entire string many times,
rather than a specific chunk. This change seems to give the desired output on
your test case, at least.

As an aside, this is how I would go about writing it. Not completely point
free, but it is closer, and significantly easier to understand.

```
import Control.Arrow ((***))
import qualified Data.Text as T

handleReplace :: Character -> T.Text -> T.Text
handleReplace (Character _ [] _ _ _) = id
handleReplace (Character _ xs _ _ _) = doReplacements $ map (T.pack *** T.pack) xs

doReplacements :: [(T.Text, T.Text)] -> T.Text -> T.Text
doReplacements reps = T.unwords . map replaceAll . T.words
    where replaceAll word = foldl replaceSingle word reps

replaceSingle :: T.Text -> (T.Text, T.Text) -> T.Text
replaceSingle word (inp, out)
    | T.head word == '/' = word
    | otherwise          = T.replace inp out word
```

Comment: ...and the best way to avoid one-letter variables is to avoid variables altogether. `s` is unnecessary, `handleReplace` can very well be written as a fold with a point-free replacer.

Comment: thank you very much! that was it. @leftaroundabout and how would i do that?

Comment: @nils8950 I can't get it to be completely points free, but I added an example of how I would clean it up. I don't think you need to worry about making it point-free, so much as modularizing it a bit.